# MS Syndication class doesn't accept valid RSS feed

Tags: c#, .net, rss

Why  do MS Syndication class doesn't accept valid RSS feed?

```
public static Stream GetResponseStream(string url)
{
    var uri = new Uri(url, true);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    return response.GetResponseStream();
}

public static void GetRSS()
{
    using (Stream stream1 = GetResponseStream("http://www.lostfilm.tv/rssdd.xml"))
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream1);
            var feeds = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error :( 
        }
    }
}
```

RSS is valid itself:

http://validator.w3.org/appc/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lostfilm.tv%2Frssdd.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SyndicationFeed` only supports RSS 2.0 and Atom 1.0 (your RSS version is 0.91).

You can use an external library, such as [Argotic Syndication Framework](http://argotic.codeplex.com/).

Install the package with [NuGet](http://nuget.org/):

```
Install-Package Argotic.Core
```

and then try with:

```cs
var feed = RssFeed.Create(new Uri("http://www.lostfilm.tv/rssdd.xml", true));
foreach (var post in feed.Channel.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(post.Title);
}
```