# Error reading reading RSS (0.91) content using C# 4.0 SyndicationFeed

Tags: c#, .net, xml, rss

I´m getting a error reading this feed: http://www.valor.com.br/rss

**Error**: SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

Error in line 2 position 2

em System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Rss20FeedFormatter.ReadXml(XmlReader reader, SyndicationFeed result)
   em System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Rss20FeedFormatter.ReadFeed(XmlReader reader)
   em System.ServiceModel.Syndication.Rss20FeedFormatter.ReadFrom(XmlReader reader)
   em System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed.Load[TSyndicationFeed](XmlReader reader)
   em System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader reader)
   em stratos.Tasks.RSSImportTask.GetSourceArticles(RSSSource source, StratosContext db) na c:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\CODE\stratos\stratos\Tasks\RSSImportTask.cs:linha 213
   em stratos.Tasks.RSSImportTask.Execute() na c:\Users\Marcelo\Documents\CODE\stratos\stratos\Tasks\RSSImportTask.cs:linha 147

Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the RSS version. SyndicationFeed only supports Atom 1.0 and RSS 2.0. The RSS returned by the URL is using version 0.91. You can try this Argotic Syndication Framework as suggested by the following link:
[MS Syndication class doesn't accept valid RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400420/ms-syndication-class-doesnt-accept-valid-rss-feed)